# Cardinality of the set $A=\left\{\frac{z_x}{z_y}: 1\le z_x \le N_x \text{ and } 1\le z_y \le N_y \right\}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Cardinality of the set  $A=\left\{\frac{z_x}{z_y}: 1\le z_x \le N_x \text{ and } 1\le z_y \le N_y \right\}$ where $z_x,z_y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Basically, the question is how many different fraction can we get with give $N_x$ and $N_y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements of $A$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the pairs $\langle z_x, z_y\rangle$ that have $\gcd(z_x, z_y)=1$ — it's clear that any two such pairs can't produce the same fraction (this is essentially the notion that fractions have a 'unique reduced form') and that any pair with a GCD $\gt 1$ can be 'reduced' to a pair with GCD $1$ by dividing by their GCD.

This quantity has been studied; it's known that the approximate asymptotics are $\frac6{\pi^2} N_x N_y$ (the strange constant here is the inverse of the [Basel Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)), and I believe the error terms are in $\Theta(\max(N_x, N_y))$ but I'm having a hard time chasing down a specific reference.  You might try starting from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Probabilities or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativelyPrime.html for more information, though.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could please include that reference once you find it>